# Should a OpenID Connect server serve twice the same token?

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, openid, openid-connect

This question might be considered as "too broad" or "good practice", but I guess there might be some pieces of RFC that could answer it.

I am currently developping my OIDC server and I am facing a situation I am not sure how to deal with.

A user has been doing a regular authorization_code flow with a web application. In the end the web application has a valid ID token. Now for some reasons the web application forget this token soon after, and the user is running the authentication flow once more:

- Should the OP serve the previous ID token, as it is still valid? Or are there some security issues here?
- If not, should the OP ask again for the user consent, or consider it already has it?

Answer (score 2):

I think you can find your answer here: https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#Authenticates. Also take note on the wording here: https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#TokenResponse, saying "ID Token value associated with the authenticated session".

My interpretation is: The ID token can be seen associated to an authenticated session that the OP might have, depending on the implementation. So yes, the OP is allowed to serve the same ID token, unless the prompt parameter of the Authentication Request requires reauthentication or consent.
If the Client always wants/needs explicit authentication and/or consent, the prompt parameter can be used for that purpose.